# OCaml fatorial is 0

Tags: ocaml, sequence, factorial

I want to have a code that calculates the Narayana numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana_number

However, it starts to present '0' for numbers over 20.

What might be failing?

```
let rec factorial n =
    if n <= 1 then 1
    else factorial (n-1) * n;;
```

Comment: " it starts to present '0'"? What is "it"? It's not the factorial function, which as others have pointed out overflows past 20. You should include the code that produces 0.

Answer (score 3):

`factorial 21` overflows and returns an incorrect result.
The `max_int` value of on my 64bit setup is 4611686018427387903, which is just between 20! and 21!.

The to get around this you can avoid actually calculating the value of n! (or k!) ub `binomial_coeff`. Instead calculate more complex values. For instance, instead of `n!/k!`, you can use `(k+1)*(k+2)*...*n`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a piece of code, that is `factorial (n)` as numerator:

```
let binomial_coeff (n:int) (k:int) =
    if k = 0 || k = n then 1
    else factorial (n) / (factorial (k) * factorial (n-k));;
```

Comment: You wrote `fatorial` instead of `factorial` in the third line

Comment: `factorial n` still overflows for `n` values greater than 20.